# Loop arrays to set value = vals[0] || vals[1] || vals[2] in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, each

I have two arrays. For example:

```
var bool = [true, false, true];
var vals = ['hi','med','lo'];
```

Using jQuery, I'd like to loop through them so that I can test each bool, and set a `var`  equal to the highest available value from the `vals` array after the first `true` from the `bool` array:

```
var value = ( bool[0] ) ? vals[0] || vals[1] || vals[2] :
                        ( bool[1] ) ? vals[1] || vals[2] : vals[2] ;
```

I'd like to make this work in a way that the arrays could have more values (but the size of the one would always match each.) Is it possible to pull this off with an `.each` function?

Comment: Too specific. Not of any use to anyone else.

Comment: I don't understand the point of the `||` operators. They're all truthy values, so you'll always get the value before the first `||`. What am I missing?

Comment: @patrick dw In the actual case the vals may not be. They are from data attributes which may be empty.

Comment: Some great stuff here. Let's see if I can put this all together to get everything ...

Comment: Is it possible that there would be no `true` value in `bool`? It seems that you're using `vals[2]` as a default without testing `bool[2]`. Just curious.

Comment: ryanve, when you give an example you should give cases where it works in more than one way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** It appears that you need the first truthy value from `vals` and `bool`. Here's a solution that doesn't require any functions.

```
var value, i = 0;

while( !bool[i] && ++i < bool.length );

while( !(value = vals[i]) && ++i < vals.length );
```

*I misunderstood the question to think that the arrays need to be truthy at the same indices. Now I see that the first true `bool` index is just the starting point for `vals`. Fixed.*

---

To explain, we have two `while` loops. In both of them, the typical `{...}` block statement has been replaced by an `;` empty statement. This is because all the work is done by the expressions between the `(...)`.

The first loop simply increments `i` until a truthy value is found in `bool`. That sets `i` to the starting point for the second loop.

The second loop does the same thing as the first, except that each time the expression runs, it sets the current `val[i]` to the `value` variable. It does this as long as `value` is assigned a "falsey" value.

This is effectively the same as your `val[0] || val[1] || val[2]` part, except it will always begin wherever the `bool` loop left `i`.

So once `value` gets a "truthy" value, or `i` exceeds the last index in the `vals` array, the loop will quit. At this point, `value` will hold either the "truthy" value that was found, or `undefined` if none was found.

---

As a function:

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/W9uBb/

```
function filterValsFromBools(bool, vals) {
    var value, i = 0;

    while (!bool[i] && ++i < bool.length);

    while (!(value = vals[i]) && ++i < vals.length);

    return value;
}

var a = filterValsFromBools(
    [true, false, true], 
    ['hi', 'med', 'lo']
);

var b = filterValsFromBools(
    [false, true, true], 
    ['hi', 'med', 'lo']
);

var c = filterValsFromBools(
    [false, true, true], 
    ['hi', 0, 'lo']
);

console.log( a, b, c );  // "hi" "med" "lo"
```

Comment: Thanks again / I see what you're going for but I'm not quite grasping it. I added `return value;` and it kept giving me `vals[1]` (the second value). Do the while loops need a statement inside `{}` after the conditions? Something to the effect of `{ value = vals[i] || vals[i++] }`

Comment: @ryanve: It's a little bit of an unusual structure, but both `while` loops have only the empty statement `;`. All the work is done by the expressions between `(...)`, so there's no need for any code in a block `{...}`. The result will be held by the `value` variable. The difference is that if there is no successful match, `result` will be `undefined`. If the last value in `vals` should be a default value, that's an easy fix. I'll update my answer with further explanation as to what is happening.

Comment: ...if you were always getting `vals[1]` then something else is wrong, or I didn't understand the requirements correctly. I'll give another update with a live example as a function.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation—I got it working! Yes there is a last value as a fallback. It actually makes the `vals` array have one extra value so I was either going to add an extra `true` to `bool` before the loop or add `value = value || fallback;` after it. Which do you think is more efficient?

Comment: @ryanve: You're welcome. Glad you got it working. Yes, `value = value || fallback` would work, or if you have it in a function, you could do `return value || fallback`. If you were to add a value, I think you'd want to add the fallback to `vals`. But the `||` solution seems the most straight forward.

Answer (score 3):

How about [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf):

```
var bool = [true, false, true];
var vals = ['hi','med','lo'];

var result = vals.slice(bool.indexOf(true));

var finalValue = result.reduce(function (a,b) {return a || b} );
```

This needs to be shimmed for IE8 and below, but there's a nice shim in that link above.

---

**EDIT**

So slice the values array from the index of the first `true`. Then reduce the sliced array until you reach the first truthy value.

Comment: It appears the OP wants the first truthy value in `vals` _starting from_ the index you just computed (Which is how I read the `||`s).

Comment: @iabstractdownvotefactory Ah that is excellent. I just need to figure out the part of getting it with the ||'s. Maybe something w/ `indexOf` ++  until it hits the of the array?

Comment: @IAbstractDownvoteFactory nice combination of `indexOf` then `reduce` +1

Comment: It's really useful to find out about some of those new functions. I didn't quite get it to work in Chrome though. (Chrome shouldn't need a patch right?)

Comment: @iabstractdownvotefactory K thx – I shall give it another try then ;)

Answer (score 2):

See [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). The important parts are:

The signature...

> > jQuery.each( collection, callback(indexInArray, valueOfElement) )

...and how to "break":

> > We can break the $.each() loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return false.

```
var bool = [true, false, true];
var vals = ['hi','med','lo'];
var result
jQuery.each(bool, function (index, val) {
   if (val) { // or val === true or whatever
     // got it, save value, stop iterating
     result = vals[index]
     return false
   }
})
```

Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var goal;
var bools = [true, false, true];
var vals = ['high', 'med', 'lo'];
jQuery.each(vals, function(i, value) {
    if (bools[i] === true) // or use if (bools[i]) but that will also be true for "truthy" non-bools
    {
        goal = value;
        return false; // this breaks from the each loop
    }
});
```